# ROBLOX Studio: How do you script a part that assigns you to a team when you click on it?

Tags: lua, roblox

ROBLOX Studio: How do you script a part that assigns you to a team when you click on it?

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation for Teams](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Player/Team). That might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are going to need to insert a Team object in the teams service in the explorer. If it doesn't show up there, click on "model" > "Services" > "Teams" and click the button "Insert": [image: Go To Model And Services]

Then Insert a Team object in the Teams service and customize it as you want.
[image: Teams Service]

After that create a part in the workspace and place a script and a click detector in it.
[image: PartScriptClickDetector]

And then, place this script in it and make changes to fit your game specifically:

```
local TeamsService = game:GetService('Teams')
-- Wirte your team's name in the wait for child
local Team = TeamsService:WaitForChild('Noobs')
local ClickDetector = script.Parent:WaitForChild('ClickDetector')

local function AssignTeam(Player)
    Player.Team = Team
end

ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(AssignTeam)
```

Also, click detector works for mobile as well.

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/ClickDetector/MouseClick

Implement a MouseClick event listener for the part. Then use the playerWhoClicked parameter to determin which player clicked. In that listener assign a Team instance to that players Team property.

Read:

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Team

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Player/Team